# Is there a way to calculate number of spl-tokens per solana block?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, anchor-client, anchor-lang

I am new to solana. Can someone suggests ways to:

1. calculate number of spl-tokens per solana block?
2. Is there any rpc methods to do so?
3. How to get solana block height in solana?

Answer (score 1):

The first question is nearly impossible, since you'll need to query all spl-token mints and sum up their supplies.  If you have a snapshot or a ledger tool, then you should be able to do it.

If, however, you just want the supply of a particular spl-token, you can do `getTokenSupply` from RPC:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method":"getTokenSupply", "params": ["3wyAj7Rt1TWVPZVteFJPLa26JmLvdb1CAKEFZm3NY75E"]}
'
```

More info at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokensupply

To get the block height, you can use `getBlockHeight` from RPC:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getBlockHeight"}
'
```

More info at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblockheight